# Upgrading project to version 2.2.0 of the Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

When upgrading a play project to 2.2.0 the following error comes up:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.0: not found
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Edit the following line in project/plugin.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

to

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Make sure you have the correct version of sbt in `build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

Comment: Now I get the following error: `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.0: not found`

Comment: I followed the steps, when I compile or run it there are not errors but when I load the webpage I'm working with it can't find any of the files in /assets/css, any idea? thanks!

Comment: What is the exact exception you are getting? What version of `play` are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225466/some-files-in-assets-css-not-found-playframework

Comment: i'm using play 2.2.0, you can see my question in the link above

Comment: Should this change not be a part of the installation of the project by play? Or is it?

Answer (score 1):

There are even more things, that you need to do to upgrade your application: [Play 2.2 migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22)

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading, you may face a problem to package your application as .war

Play 2.1.4 onwards, support for packaging into a war file has been withdrawn. There is a workaround for the same which can help you in generating war file. You fool the compiler and let it think that we are using earlier version of Play. For details refer to the following link :-

[Create War from Play 2.2.1 application](http://play2war.blogspot.com)

It is working till day for me :)