# Some files in /assets/css not found [Playframework]

Tags: css, playframework, assets

Hi I was having this problem with an unresolved dependency:

> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.0:
>   not found

and then I found the solution here: [Upgrading project to version 2.2.0 of the Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045124/upgrading-project-to-version-2-2-0-of-the-play-framework)

I followed the steps now when I compile or run play there are not errors but when I load the webpage I'm working with it can't find some of the files in /assets/css. After all the changes proposed on the solution I use the command `clean`, but still the same problem [Status Code:404 Not Found]. [image]

This is how I call the files in assets:

```
> layout.scala.html

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/layout.min.css")" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/style.min.css")" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/blocks.min.css")" type="text/css">
```

I'm using play 2.2.0. Any idea about how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Did you start the application with Play or SBT? Since you are in Dev mode the minified versions of CSS is not available, so you have to fix the links.

Comment: Are you using [reverse routing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting) to link your assets?

Comment: I updated my question, I'm not using reverse routing and I start the application with Play

Comment: You only showing how you trying to include the ones that don't work. The ones that do work, are you importing them in the same manner?