# SBT. Resolving dependencies for play sbt-plugin

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I use sbt `0.13.1` (`myProject/project/build.properties/` has `sbt.version=0.13.1`)

In my `myProject/project/play.sbt`

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

I tried many versions, but whatever I do, It can not resolve that dependency. I end up with error like this:

**[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.2.1: not found**

I even try to put `scalaVersion := "2.9.1"` to `play.sbt` to be consistent with repositories (in case if does matter):

[/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/)

But it does not work.

Eh.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading project to version 2.2.0 of the Play Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045124/upgrading-project-to-version-2-2-0-of-the-play-framework)

Answer (score 5):

Set project/plugin.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

Also the correct version of sbt in build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

[Full migration guide to play 2.2](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/Migration22)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Play 2.2.0 the group id is now `com.typesafe.play` so the following should work:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

"If you're running on [...] anything that can run a Bash script, I highly recommend the [launch script](https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt) from sbt-extras." ([dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115478/dave) at [stackoverflow question 8721338](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721338/sbt-unresolved-dependencies-sbt-2-9-10-7-4-sbt-2-9-10-7-7)). It helped me, too.